# Animate UITableView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm implementing an Accordion menu UI with nested UITableview. First, I created a custom UITableViewCell, it has a UITableView in it. When the cell tapped, the top level tableview's cell height will be calculated and the table view will be updated animatedly by `[UITableView beginUpdates]` and `[UITableView endUpdates]`.

While updating the cell's height, I also change the 2nd level tableview's height animatedly. This change is being done by auto layout. And during the 2nd level tableview change, I want some row animation to be displayed. What I'm doing is, insert or delete rows one by one with row animation for example left to right.

My problem is, when 'opening' the top level menu, the cell's height become bigger animatedly, the 2nd level tableview's row animation is also correctly displayed. But, when 'closing' it, the cell's height become smaller animatedly while the 2nd level tableview's row animation cannot be seen. The rows of the 2nd tableview just disappeared immediately.
 Is there anyone can tell me how to correctly implement this animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement the Accordion functionality, I would recommend you a simpler way.
You need to manage one data source, which you will pass to mother tableview (eg: array) which will contain an array on whose each index containing number of indexes as Dictionaries. This dictionary must have one Bool Key. Now as their is one delegate of UITableview "viewForHedderInSection", create one UITableviewCell and return to it. Now you just need to update the Bool value in dictionary. The cell row you want to open just make that bool value to Yes and rest to No, and reload tableview. This way you will achieve Accordion.
Now to its each cell i.e. UIView add an UITableView and update its data source by adding and deleting rows and to make these 2 UITableview function differently make there instances differently.
I think this way this functionality can be achieved.

Comment: I think you are right. That's the best way that I can imagine. Thanks.